# How to detect song playing is completed?

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, android-music-player

I am playing a song with the help of Media Player using following code,

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource( "sound_file_filepath" );
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Now i have a toggle kind of image in my .xml file which first shows a play image. After clicking/touching the play image it will start the song and replace the image with stop image.

Now my question is how can i know that my sound has finished playing ? I am very well aware of isPlaying() method, it returns true if song is running and false if not. But when  & where should i check this condition to display the play image again ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe something like this can help,

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
// When song is ended then media player automatically called onCompletion method.
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
{
    // Write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like OnPrepared Listener u have OnCompletion Listener like below

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.i("Completion Listener","Song Complete");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Do the work after completion of audio
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason need another solution, as I did. This might work for you:

```
    if(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == mPlayer.getDuration()){
        // Do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code syntax-

```
Audio_object=document.getElementById('audio_tag_id');
if(Audio_object.currentTime==Audio_object.duration)
//the audio object has completely played.
```

`audio_tag_id` is the id of the `<audio>`-element.

Comment: This is Javascript?